# HttpServletRequest object is getting override once thread started

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, servlets, threadpool

I am trying to execute a method asynchronously, where am passing a httpServletRequest object as parameter. But the passed request is getting override once the thread got started.

Here is the sample code

```
class sampleServlet extends servlet{
        doPost(req,res){
        method1(req);
    }
}

method1(httpservletrequest){
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            method2(httpservletrequest)
    }).start();
}

method2(httpSservletRequest){
//The request object here is different from the passed object
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different class say ThreadSample implementing the Runnable interface and have the HttpServletRequest as a member of the class. When you create an object of the ThreadSample class, pass your httpServletRequest as a constructor argument and then in the run method use the instance member httpServletRequest while calling method2.

The code will somewhat look like:

```
public class ThreadSample implements Runnable
{

    private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;



    public ThreadSample(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
    {
        this.httpServletRequest = httpServletRequest;
    }



    public void run()
    {
        method2(this.httpServletRequest);
    }

}
```

In your doPost method of the Servlet class, you can use ThreadSample like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadSample(httpServletRequest));
thread.start();
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: i have tried the same approach u suggested. The parameter passed and the parameter received are different. If i pass any parameters other than httpservlerequest those values are properly passed to the method.